# how can i make dialog plugin for vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

i wanna make a dialog that is promise and when a user click on "YES" button , promise get true value .
for exampleyu click on "DELETE" button and below code is runned , and at first a dialog is shown and when you click on "YES" then it returns  "True" and the item will be deleted .
[image]

```
  async onDel(item: any) {
    let confirm = await this.$dialog.show()
    if (confirm) this.delete(item)
  }
```

i need this dialog because i think this is so clean code.
so , HOW can i write dialog plugin that return a promise ??

Comment: How would you write the plugin if it didn't return a Promise? once you show that, making it return a Promise will be simple

Comment: yes it is simple but i want to when i call 
this.$dialog.show()
the dialog shows

Comment: OK, so show your non-promise plugin code, and then you can be helped to return a Promise as you desire

Comment: this is plugins/dialog.js
```
export default function ({ store }, inject) {
  inject('dialog', () => store.commit('toggleDial'))
}
```

Comment: wow, that one line does everything!!! I didn't realise vuejs was THAT good

Comment: This one line just show/hide alert component